# Validations while navigation between tabs in Tabview [Nativescript with angular]

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have used Tabview in my application. There are six different tabs in component.
I need to do validations while try to navigate to next tab likewise between all the tabs.

Like required field validations, If any required fields are not entered means users can’t able to navigate next tab.

Any idea on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

#### XML

```
<Page>
<TabView selectedIndexChanged="onSelectedIndexChanged">
...
</TabView>
</Page>
```

#### TS

```
 export function onSelectedIndexChanged(args) {...}
```

Based on the selected Index you check for validation and redirect it back to the previous index or route it to Login Screen or whatever.